# Hello, we are currently doing an array task but I am new to C#

Tags: c#

We must find the average and or sum of the 5 numbers inputted by the user, but I am unsure how to do this. Any help is appreciated! This is my code so far: 
Basically I would need help completing the sum of the numbers inputted, also how to use the arrays with a number inputted later on in the code considering it proclaims 'int unassigned'.

```
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int numofnum;
            int[] numbers = new int[numofnum];
            int index;
            string avsu;
            int average;
            index = 0;

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number of numbers you would like to find the average for, or add together: ");
            numofnum = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


            Console.WriteLine("Would you like to find the average or sum of these numbers? (average/sum)");
            avsu = Console.ReadLine();


            if (avsu == "average")
            {


            do 
            {
                Console.Write("Please enter Number to find the average of: " + index);
                numbers[index] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                index = index + 1;
            } while (index < numofnum);

            index = 0;

            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You entered the following values: ");
                Console.WriteLine("Number " + index + ": " + numbers[index]);
                index = index + 1;

                Console.WriteLine("The average of these numbers is: " + (numbers[index] / 2));
            } while (index < numofnum);

                else if (avsu == "sum")
            {


            do 
            {
                Console.Write("Please enter Number " + index + " to add: ");
                numbers[index] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                index = index + 1;
            } while (index < numofnum);

            index = 0;

            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You entered the following values: ");
                Console.WriteLine("Number " + index + ": " + numbers[index]);
                index = index + 1;

                Console.WriteLine("The sim of these numbers is: " + (numbers[index])); // UNSURE HOW TO DISPLAY THE SUM!!!!
            } while (index < numofnum);
            Console.ReadLine();

            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are LINQ methods to do this for you. `var sum = numbers.Sum();` and `var avg = numbers.Average();`

Comment: That code shouldn't compile as you seem to be missing at least one `}`. Please post the correct code, and tell us which line you are getting `int unassigned` on, and post the complete error message, not just a summary.

Comment: Itsme86 thanks, I did see this online but I couldn't get it to work is there anyway you could write it up in context with my work? I appreciate the help.

Comment: Also Ken I appreciate it but I posted this as I got off for the night so I will have to do so tomorrow, I can try explain it better. So basically the array line int[] numbers wants me to assign a value to numofnum which I do later in the code but it still doesn't compile.

Answer (score 0):

Will this help?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(
        "Please enter the number of numbers you would like to find the average for, or add together: ");
    int numofnum = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    int[] numbers = new int[numofnum];

    Console.WriteLine("Would you like to find the average or sum of these numbers? (average/sum)");
    var avsu = Console.ReadLine();
    var sum = 0;

    if (avsu != "average" && avsu != "sum")
    {
        return;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < numofnum; i++)
    {
        Console.Write("Please enter Number " + i + " to add: ");
        numbers[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < numofnum; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You entered the following values: ");
        Console.WriteLine("Number " + i + ": " + numbers[i]);
    }

    if (avsu == "sum")
    {
        sum = numbers.Sum();
        Console.WriteLine("The sim of these numbers is: " + sum);
    }

    if (avsu == "average")
    {
        var average = sum / numbers.Length;
        Console.WriteLine("The average of these numbers is: " + average);
    }
}
```

Comment: NP. For cycles are better for your case and almost nobody uses do {} while() nowadays.

Comment: Ah thanks, it is just sixth form stuff - they seem to want us to do it.

Comment: So the main place I was going wrong was not assigning a value to numofnum before the array?

Comment: Could you explain a tad more how the for cycles work?

Comment: Do-while is not wrong but when changing index in a cycle you are using for. In other cases while is used instead of do - while, as it is essentially the same but has nicer syntax. For cycles in short: for(int i = 0; i < n;i++) means int i = 0; while(i < n) { do sth..; i = i + 1;}. It does the incrementing, initialising and the condition in one row for you. Here is some more info: https://www.dotnetperls.com/for